# Why am I getting "[Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable" under these circumstances?

Tags: linux, serial-port

I'm running the Python script below on Ubuntu 20.04. My user is a member of `dialout`.

```
$ ./test_serial.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_serial.py", line 20, in <module>
    data = os.read(fd, 1024)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

$ ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb 10 16:12 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 1 Feb 10 17:56 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

The script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os
import termios

DEVICE = "/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_AB0NTUNC-if00-port0"
DEVICE = "/dev/ttyUSB0"

fd = os.open(DEVICE, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)
if fd >= 0:
    if os.isatty(fd):
        # Configure the serial port.
        tios = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        tios[2] &= ~termios.CBAUD
        tios[2] |= termios.B115200
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, tios)

data = os.read(fd, 1024)

print(data)
```

dmesg:

```
[ 1254.255499] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1254.256536] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1254.256604] ftdi_sio 1-3:1.0: device disconnected
[ 1257.829592] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1257.985421] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[ 1257.985441] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1257.985448] usb 1-3: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 1257.985454] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 1257.985460] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: A500INN8
[ 1257.989360] ftdi_sio 1-3:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 1257.989490] usb 1-3: Detected FT232RL
[ 1257.990398] usb 1-3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 4076.157451] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4076.311520] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[ 4076.311537] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4076.311544] usb 1-1: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 4076.311550] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 4076.311554] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: AB0NTUNC
[ 4076.315282] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 4076.315368] usb 1-1: Detected FT232RL
[ 4076.316294] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

Comment: You specified NONBLOCK and then did a read. "EAGAIN The file descriptor fd refers to a file other than a socket and has been marked non‐blocking (O_NONBLOCK), and the read would block. "

Comment: When you specify NONBLOCK mode, then you have to program for results such as EAGAIN.  If you want to keep your program simple (and efficiently utilize the scheduling capabilities of the OS), then don't use non-blocking mode.  Unless you really know what you are doing (and have the additional code in place), use of non-blocking mode typically is less efficient and slower than the simpler blocking mode.

Comment: @stark @sawdust Thanks. I think I got it my mind, from some other posts, that this meant the device was somehow tied up by another resource. I didn't realize it was `EAGAIN`. So I'll simply handle this as "data is not available".